# MySQL alias for SELECT * columns

Tags: mysql, alias

I'm creating a view that is using data that comes from the same table twice. As a result, same column names appear twice.

Thus, i need to give aliases to these columns. If i were to do it, i'd write it as:

```
SELECT u.* as 'one_*', u2.* as 'two_*'
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN relationships r ON u.id=r.id_one
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON r.id_two=u2.id
```

But that doesn't work. Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

Here's the data i'm actually getting:

```
|  id  | name |  id  | name |
   1     john    2     alex
```

Here's the data i'd like to get (while still using a `SELECT u.*, u2.*`):

```
|  id  | name |  brother_id  | brother_name |
   1     john        2             alex
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm misunderstanding.. do you need to get each column from both tables returned, or is a UNION like @matthewh provided what you need?

Comment: Your example uses an implicit cross join, 99,99% sure that's not what you want. Use explicit SQL '92 join syntax instead.

Comment: You perfectly understood, but your answer is what i was trying to avoid by using "multiple aliases" :)

Comment: @Johan there's nothing implicit in my query, i'm just showing you the first part. After that there are two left joins, selecting the right `u2` for each `u`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't use `*` with an alias. Aliases can be used for individual columns.

You'll have to alias each column instead..

So unfortunately, if you have a lot of columns, you'll need to go:

```
SELECT u.col1 AS u_col1
    , u.col2 AS u_col2
    , u.col3 AS u_col3
    -- etc
    , u2.col1 AS u2_col1
    , u2.col2 AS u2_col2
    , u2.col3 AS u2_col3
    -- etc
FROM table1 AS u
-- INNER JOIN / LEFT OR RIGHT OUTER JOIN / ,
    table2 AS u2
```

Comment: Is there a way to shorten this? I mean... Any way to shorten the amount of syntax where you don't have to say "AS" for every alias?

Comment: You dont need the "AS".. u.col1 u_col1 is fine. Doesn't shorten your effort much, but might make the code easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) query:

e.g.

`select a.typeid, a.typename from MYTABLE a where a.typeid=3 UNION select a.typeid, a.typename from MYTABLE a where a.typeid=4`

Comment: I don't think the union will work since he wants to retrieve columns from both instances of the same table, unless I misunderstood...

Comment: Ah, perhaps I have misread the question. I think your answer is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I recently had the problem and came up with a solution.

First query the table and get the names of the columns

ex.

"SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name"

then use a loop to concat a prefix to the column name

ex

foreach ($all_columns as $the_column){
$alias_select .= ', '.$table_name.'.'.$the_column['Field'].' alias_'.$the_column['Field'];
}
then just put this string into your query and you will get another set of values all with the prefix_column_name.

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just use `SELECT *` and then in your code refer to `u.field1` and `u2.field2`?

Comment: Field names are the same since i'm getting data from the same table twice for one row in the resultset. If i'm running the query without using any aliases, i don't have any way to tell what one column belongs to.

Comment: You didn't put your whole query, so there was no way of knowing that.  Hiding information does limit how much I can help, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. i updated the question, if that can help :)

Comment: You need to put the whole query you're having trouble with - the most important bit of information, the `FROM ...` is missing.  Put something that if copy-and-pasted into a SQL command should work.

Comment: updated again, but i really doubt that'll help for that problem

Comment: Well, looking at that, have you tried my suggestion?  In your PHP or whatever, don't just put `$r['field1']`, put `$r['u.field1']` or `$r['u2.field1']` .

Comment: That's not how mysql works... The rows are always retrieved by column name and not prepended with their table name sadly

Answer (score -2):

SELECT alias.* does certainly work in mysql >= 5.6

Comment: this doesn't address the question...  OP wishes to automatically rename the columns with something like the table alias, which doesn't happen with this