# Join data from one table based on 2 values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT   user_accounts.uacc_id,
         user_accounts.uacc_username,
         ride_rides.ride_type,
         ride_rides.ride_num_seats,
         ride_rides.ride_price_seat,
         ride_rides.ride_accept_nm,
         ride_rides.ride_split_cost,
         ride_rides.ride_from,
         ride_rides.ride_from_lat,
         ride_rides.ride_from_lng,
         ride_rides.ride_to,
         ride_rides.ride_to_lat,
         ride_rides.ride_to_lng,
         user_profiles.upro_image_name,
         ride_times.ridetms_id,
         ride_times.ridetms_return,
         ride_times.ridetms_depart_date,
         ride_times.ridetms_depart_time,
         ride_times.ridetms_return_date,
         ride_times.ridetms_return_time,
         depart_times.dpttme_text
FROM ride_times 
    LEFT JOIN ride_rides 
        ON ride_rides.ride_id = ride_times.ridetms_ride_fk 
    LEFT JOIN user_accounts 
        ON ride_rides.ride_uacc_fk = user_accounts.uacc_id
    LEFT JOIN user_profiles 
        ON user_profiles.upro_uacc_fk = user_accounts.uacc_id
    LEFT JOIN depart_times 
        ON depart_times.dpttme_id = ride_times.ridetms_depart_time
WHERE ride_times.ridetms_id = ?"
```

Right now, I have the query pulling a text representation of the data from ride_times.ridetms_depart_time in the last join, and it works fine. However, I need to do the same with another column in the ride_times table. I think I need to use an alias, but after reading several sources on aliases, I can't wrap my head around how to change the call.

Also, 100 brownie points for any feedback about any glaring mistakes in this call. It is my first attempt at using JOINs.

take care,
lee

Thanks to the responses I've received so far. Here is the structure of the tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE `depart_times` (
`dpttme_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dpttme_text` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dpttme_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `ride_rides` (
  `ride_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ride_uacc_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ride_date_added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ride_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ride_from` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ride_from_lat` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ride_from_lng` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ride_to` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ride_to_lat` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ride_to_lng` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ride_num_seats` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ride_price_seat` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ride_accept_nm` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'accept non-monetary items',
  `ride_split_cost` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ride_notes` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ride_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE `ride_times` (
  `ridetms_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ridetms_ride_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ridetms_date_added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ridetms_depart_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `ridetms_depart_time` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `ridetms_return` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ridetms_return_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `ridetms_return_time` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ridetms_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE `user_accounts` (
  `uacc_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uacc_group_fk` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uacc_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_ip_address` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_salt` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_activation_token` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_forgotten_password_token` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_forgotten_password_expire` datetime NOT NULL,
  `uacc_update_email_token` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_update_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uacc_suspend` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uacc_fail_login_attempts` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_fail_login_ip_address` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `uacc_date_fail_login_ban` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Time user is banned until due to repeated failed logins',
  `uacc_date_last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `uacc_date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uacc_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uacc_id` (`uacc_id`),
  KEY `uacc_group_fk` (`uacc_group_fk`),
  KEY `uacc_email` (`uacc_email`),
  KEY `uacc_username` (`uacc_username`),
  KEY `uacc_fail_login_ip_address` (`uacc_fail_login_ip_address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE `user_profiles` (
  `upro_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `upro_uacc_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `upro_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upro_blackberry_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upro_yahoo_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upro_skype_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upro_gmail_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upro_image_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT 'default.jpg',
  PRIMARY KEY (`upro_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `upro_id` (`upro_id`),
  KEY `upro_uacc_fk` (`upro_uacc_fk`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So, to clarify:

Right now I am pulling some text from depart_times based on ride_times.ridetms_depart_time. I need to also pull some text form depart_times based on ride_times.ridetms_return_time.

Comment: Which column do you want join with which other one? Provide more info please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Right now, it is pulling a value from ride_times.depart_time and then joins a text representation of that value from a table called depart_times. What I need to do now is join data from depart_times based on a value pulled from ride_times.return_time(which is not currently in the SQL I posted because I'm not sure how to fit it in there)

Comment: Pl provide your table structure

Comment: For formatting your query, read [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#basic-links), also linked as the "?" button above your post (near the formatting buttons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

After LOTS more searching, I found this post:

[MySQL alias for SELECT * columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341136/mysql-alias-for-select-columns)

I have revised my statement to the following and it is working properly:

```
SELECT user_accounts.uacc_id,
                        user_accounts.uacc_username,
                        ride_rides.*,
                        user_profiles.upro_image_name,
                        ride_times.*,
                        dpt1.dpttme_text AS dep_text,
                        dpt2.dpttme_text AS ret_text
                FROM ride_times
                    LEFT JOIN ride_rides 
                        ON ride_rides.ride_id = ride_times.ridetms_ride_fk 
                    LEFT JOIN user_accounts 
                        ON ride_rides.ride_uacc_fk = user_accounts.uacc_id
                    LEFT JOIN user_profiles 
                        ON user_profiles.upro_uacc_fk = user_accounts.uacc_id
                    LEFT JOIN depart_times AS dpt1
                        ON dpt1.dpttme_id = ride_times.ridetms_depart_time
                    LEFT JOIN depart_times AS dpt2
                        ON dpt2.dpttme_id = ride_times.ridetms_return_time  
                WHERE ride_times.ridetms_id = ?
```

Thanks very much to everyone who attempted to help me.

take care,
lee

Comment: Also...Kudos to whoever suggested the change in my SQL formatting. That contributed to helping me see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have joined all the tables already, Just put the condition with the WHERE clause Like :

```
WHERE
ride_times.ridetms_id = ?
AND 
depart_times.column_name1 = ride_times.return_time
```

Does this answer your question?

Well, I must point out this line:

```
LEFT JOIN depart_times ON depart_times.dpttme_id = ride_times.ridetms_depart_time
```

Just feels like, something wrong with the schema. But, that is also a guess from my side seeing the namings..

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is possible. Like I said, this is my first attempt at using joins. I've posted the structure of the tables involved.

Comment: which column u want in place of my depart_times.column_name1?

Comment: I am not wanting to replace the data, rather, I am trying to find out how to access depart_times a second time. Right now, it returns a value in depart_times.dpttms_txt based on ride_times.ridetms_depart_time. I need it to access depart_times a second time and return text based on the value of ride_times.ridetms_return_time.