# Avoid "#1060 - Duplicate column name" Error, but still using SELECT *

Tags: mysql, sql, view, key

I have 2 tables, advertisers and campaigns. Both have more fields I care to list and both have a primary key "id". I'd like to create a view without having to enter all fields manually using * instead. I keep getting the "duplicate column" error. Is it possible to do this via * at all or is my only option to enter all column names and setting aliases for the IDs?

```
  CREATE VIEW VIEW_CAMPAIGNS AS 

  SELECT *, 
      advertisers.id as adv_id,
      campaigns.id as camp_id

  FROM  campaigns, advertisers
  WHERE advertisers.id = advertiser_id
```

Still returns #1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'

Comment: Are you trying to say that it can't be done with SELECT * ?

Comment: Yes, by saying *, you mean all columns from both tables, the fact that you're also adding 2 more columns explicitly and giving them a new alias doesn't change the fact that you've already selected all columns from both tables.

Comment: Thanks. There is no way to exclude a column from * ?

Comment: Yes. But I'm also saying don't use * period. Best practice is to always name (and fully identify) all columns.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll just type out 40 column names now ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL (and other standard databases) by using the `using` form of the `join` instead of the `on`clause.

Unfortunately, you can do that here because the join keys have different ids in the two tables.  If they had the same name, you would just do:

CREATE VIEW VIEW_CAMPAIGNS AS 
      SELECT *, 
      FROM  campaigns c join
            advertisers a
            using (advertisers_id);

The nearest you can do is to choose the bigger table, use `*` for that and then list all the columns for the other table.

Or, better yet, just use the `information_schame.columns` table to generate the column names.  Something like:

```
select (case when column_name = 'id' and table_name = 'campaigns' then `c.campaign_id`
             when column_name = 'id' and table_name = 'advertisers' then 'a.advertiser_id'
             when table_name = 'campaigns' then concat('c.', column_name)
             when table_name = 'advertisers' then concat('a.', column_name)
        end) as column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name in ('campaigns, 'advertisers')
```

Comment: Thanks a million! 'CREATE VIEW VIEW_CAMPAIGNS AS SELECT *, FROM campaigns c join advertisers a using (advertisers_id);' solved my issue of duplicate cols

Answer (score 0):

you can do it that why

```
  CREATE VIEW VIEW_CAMPAIGNS AS 

  SELECT u.id AS u_id
       ....
  , u2.id AS u2_id

  FROM  campaigns u
  INNER JOIN advertisers u2
  ON u.id = u2.advertiser_id
```

then its automatically columns are differentited .

- for performance : better use columns which you need only and not using `*` . to not select all columns (40) every time.

EDIT:

Aliases can be used for individual columns.

You'll have to alias each column instead

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341136/mysql-alias-for-select-columns)

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What do the (...) mean? If I need to add the field-names/aliases there the whole undertaking is pointless. The idea was to use *. Everybody basically says it can't be done. (?)