# MYSQL tables with same column name

Tags: php, mysql

Fetching and print results from multiple tables that have same column name. Here's my query: I am trying to fetch the column `salt` from `login` and `cookie` table.

```
SELECT login.salt
     , cookie.salt 
  FROM login
     , cookie 
 WHERE login.user_id 
   AND cookie.user_id = :user_id`

login
+---------------------------+
| user_id |       salt      |
+---------+-----------------+
| 1       |    fromLogin    |
| 2       |    fromLogin    |

cookie
+---------------------------+
| user_id |       salt      |
+---------+-----------------+
| 1       |    fromCookie   |
| 2       |    fromCookie   |
```

The result was:

`Array ( [salt] => fromCookie )`

How can i print both result out?

`PHP`

```
$user_id = 1;

$sql = "SELECT login.salt, cookie.salt FROM login, cookie WHERE login.user_id AND cookie.user_id = :user_id";

$params = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id
        );

$stmt = $db->justConnect()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: use alias in query to differentiate.

Comment: If i have to fetch salt from maybe 100 tables, so I just do like `s1`, `s2`, `s3` ...

Comment: Start with a good (and fairly current) book or tutorial on PHP and MySQL. This is basic stuff. And if you have 100 tables, something's gone very, very wrong.

Comment: @Jimmy "WHERE  login.user_id AND cookie.user_id = :user_id" just curious if its correct syntax?

Comment: Yes, It turn out just fine. If i have more tables, i wouldn't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `alias` with query.

```
$user_id = 1;

$sql = "SELECT login.salt as loginSalt, cookie.salt as cookieSalt FROM login, cookie WHERE login.user_id AND cookie.user_id = :user_id";

$params = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id
        );

$stmt = $db->justConnect()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use alias in mysql

```
 $sql = "SELECT login.salt as s1, cookie.salt as s2 
         FROM login, cookie 
         WHERE login.user_id 
           AND cookie.user_id = :user_id";
```

For more info refer to  [MySQL alias for SELECT * columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341136/mysql-alias-for-select-columns)

Comment: Its a bad idea around here to quote w3schools

Comment: Thanks to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

use alias SELECT login.salt **as login_salt**

Answer (score 0):

Try alias, An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name.

```
  $sql = "SELECT login.salt as s1, cookie.salt as s2 FROM login, cookie WHERE login.user_id AND cookie.user_id = :user_id";
```

[Reference 1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html)

[Reference 2](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score 0):

set alias for your columns:

```
SELECT login.salt as login_salt, cookie.salt as cookie_salt FROM login, cookie WHERE login.user_id AND cookie.user_id = :user_id
```